# Функция со сложным if js

Tags: javascript

У меня есть две кнопки, допустим, одна кнопка со значением(value) "text". Вторая пустая. 
Когда я нажимаю на кнопку "text", value этой кнопки сохраняется.

```
window.SaveValues = function (Value) {
    newValue = Value.value;
};
```

Затем я нажимаю на пустую кнопку и ее значение становится "text".

```
window.ChangeValue = function (Element) {
    Element.value = newValue;
    newValue = " "
};
```

Механизм понятен.
Но я вообще не представляю, как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии левой кнопкой мыши, менялось значение, при нажатии правой, становилось снова пустым. Ибо у одной функции тип window, у другой будет тип document со всеми вытекающими. Js знаю очень плохо, только начала, поэтому помогите, пожалуйста, как сделать вообще не представлю.

Для точности показываю html код

```
 <div class="qwerty"><input value=" " onclick="ChangeValue(this)" type="button"></div>
<div class="qwerty"><input value="text" onclick="SaveValues(this)" type="button"></div>
```

Comment: добавлять свои методы и свойства в window - плохая практика. Отучайтесь от неё.

Comment: Я не вижу другого решения ввиду незнания js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Откровенно говоря, непонятна задача. Если ориентироваться на это

> чтобы при нажатии левой кнопкой мыши, менялось значение, при нажатии правой, становилось снова пустым

то решение примет следующий вид (чистый JS)

```js
//обращаемся к испытуемому элементу
var input = document.querySelector("input");
//устанавливаем обработчик события "нажатие левой кнопки мыши"
input.addEventListener("click", function () {
    //обращаемся ко второй кнопке, забираем ее значение value
    this.value = document.querySelectorAll('input')[1].value;
});
//устанавливаем обработчик события "нажатие правой кнопки мыши"
input.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (event) {
    //отменяем стандартное поведение при нажатии правой кнопки мыши
    event.preventDefault();
    //устанавливаем новое пустое значение
    this.value = "";
});
```

```html
<div class="qwerty"><input value=" " type="button"></div>
<div class="qwerty"><input value="text" type="button"></div>
```

Все это не забываем обернуть в обработчик события загрузки страницы и удача будет на вашей стороне :)